# Inserting Date to Database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to insert a date of birth into the database just one table but it's inserting `0000-00-00`. I have a form that takes a `date` input or where `<input type="date">`. My insert command is:

```
   if (($myname = $_GET['your_name']) && ($phone = $_GET['phone']) && 
      ($dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['dob'])))) {
   $command = "INSERT INTO form_data (id, name, phone, dob) 
              VALUES ('', '".$db->real_escape_string($myname)."', 
              '".$db->real_escape_string($phone)."', '".$db->$dob."')";
```

My script works except the `$dob`. How do you handle an HTML5 input "date" input type into the database correctly? (I searched but didn't seem to work when I tried their suggestions here).

Comment: What runtime or SQL error do you get?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747254/how-to-interpret-html5-input-date-value-using-php

Comment: @Windwaker yes I tried converting didn't work

Comment: @mario didn't get any errors

Comment: Am I off here, or should you omit the `$` before `dob` at `$db->$dob`?

Comment: I see you're converting `?dob=x` into a UNIX timestamp without any verification or validation. I suggest spacing your code out first and looking at intermediate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['dob'])` to `$dob`, but later you try to reference it as `$db->$dob`. What you probably want it so to handle it just like the other variables and use `$db->real_escape_string($dob)`:

```
$command = "INSERT INTO form_data (id, name, phone, dob) 
  VALUES ('', '".$db->real_escape_string($myname)."', 
  '".$db->real_escape_string($phone)."', '".$db->real_escape_string($dob)."')";
```

To make it more readable, I'd use `sprintf` though.

```
$command = sprintf("INSERT INTO form_data (id, name, phone, dob) VALUES ('', '%s',  '%s', '%s')",
  $db->real_escape_string($myname),
  $db->real_escape_string($phone),
  $db->real_escape_string($dob));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest formatting your code so it's easier to read, and not doing assignments inside `if` blocks.

```
$myname = $_GET['your_name'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$dob = strtotime( $_GET['dob'] );

if( !empty( $myname ) && !empty( $phone ) && $dob !== false ) {
    $dob = date('Y-m-d', $dob );


    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO form_data ( id, name, phone, dob ) VALUES ( \'\', ?, ?, ? )');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $myname);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $phone);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $dob);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
}
```

Note how I use mysqli instead of mysql_. It's safer.

Answer (score 0):

By using `$db->$dob` in your `VALUES` set you're trying to access a member of `$db` called whatever value `$dob` is set to.  You should be using `$dob` instead.